# Get HashMap as Result for select

Tags: mybatis

Hi i want query database with myBatis and want return Map

I have daoInterface Like

```
public interface IDocDao extends IBasicDao {
    public Map<Integer, Integer> getDocByA();
}
```

And mapper

```
<select id="getDocByA" resultMap="myHashMap">
    SELECT b_id, count(1) AS count FROM table_a GROUP BY b_id
</select>
```

And need to return 1 map with all this values, not List of Maps

thx. Pavel

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a `HashMap`, you need to set it as a `resultType`, not as a `resultMap`. You don't need to define `myHashMap`, `hashmap` is enough.

```
<select id="getDocByA" resultType="hashmap">
    SELECT b_id, count(1) AS count FROM table_a GROUP BY b_id
</select>
```

Comment: Not working: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2

Comment: I call method from client through service and service call directly this methods (Maybe is there some call feature in core framework)

Comment: I think the service calls your method via `selectOne` method of `SqlSession`, it needs to call it either directly or via `selectMap`. If I can think of a workaround, I'll try to write. (Deleted my first comment since i figured out it wasn't right.)

Answer (score 0):

In your way, mybatis will return this:
[{b_id=b_id1, count=count1}, {b_id=b_id2, count=count2}]. So you need to define a list to receive this data, then you can convert it into a Map by additional code to loop the list.